# Динамический массив типа char

Tags: c, массивы, char

Пишу словарик и совсем запуталась в коде. Тестирую функцию, которая читает текстовый файл с матрицей размера `counter*3` и читает его в соответствующий массив.

Вот сам код:

```
char *dict;
FILE *f;
f = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
FILE* in = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
if (in == NULL) //если файл не открылся
{
    perror("File is not opened!\n");
}
size_t counter = 0;
int ch, pre = EOF;
FILE *ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
{
    pre = ch;
    if (ch == '\n')
        ++counter;

    putchar(ch);
}
if (pre == EOF)
    puts("File is empty!");
else if (pre != '\n')
{
    ++counter;
    puts("");
}
puts("");
dict = new char[counter][3];
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 0; j++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%d", (dict+i*3+j));
        printf("%d", *(dict + i * 3 + j));
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста, не могли бы вы объяснить, почему сам массив не хочет задаваться? Компилятор (MSVS) пишет, что для `char *` нельзя `(char(counter)[3])`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разбираться.
Вы объявили словарь как

```
char *dict;
```

это лишено смысла, подобные указатели ссылаются на одну строку, а насколько я понял вам нужен двумерный массив **целых чисел**, тем более что у вас в `fscanf` считывание именно целых десятичных чисел (`%d`)  тогда вам надо сделать объявление таким

```
int **dict;
```

далее, `operator new` может выделять память под один объект либо под одномерный массив, а для двумерного память нужно выделять в 2 этапа

```
dict = new int*[counter];
for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
    dict[i] = new int[3];
```

и ещё одно уточнение - использование `new` это всё-таки `С++`, а не `С`. Для чистого `С` память выделяется функцией `malloc`

```
dict = (int**)malloc(counter * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
    dict[i] = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
```

И последнее - рассмотрим ваше считывание

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 0; j++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%d", (dict+i*3+j));
        printf("%d", *(dict + i * 3 + j));
    }
}
```

у вас опечатка для ограничения `j`, и подобная запись для доступа к требуемому элементу массива неудобна для восприятия, плюс в параметры `scanf` необходимо передавать адрес требуемой переменной, это нужно заменить на

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%d", &dict[i][j]));
        printf("%d", dict[i][j]);
    }
}
```